# How to change pinned packages in mamba package manager

Tags: python, conda, mamba

When I try to install a python package in a minimamba distribution (mamba 0.14), there is no dependency solution for the python version installed (shown as pinned package below).
How can I allow this package to be downgraded to allow a dependency solution?

```
(base) C:\Users\user>mamba install nipy

(...)

Pinned packages:
  - python 3.9.4

Encountered problems while solving:
  - package nipy-0.4.1-py37hfa6e2cd_1001 requires python >=3.7,<3.8.0a0, but none of the providers can be installed
```

I have tried the --no-pin parameter with no changes.

Comment: What is a "Pinned package" in the first place? sorry for the noob question

Comment: A "Pinned package" is one you cannot change

Comment: So that particular package at that specific version is required? @tiagoams

Comment: @SkyScraper It is more the starting point, in this case python 3.9.4, for which a set of dependencies must be found. You might not need this python to be this version in which case see solutions below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you try `mamba install python=3.7 nipy`?
This should downgrade `python` package to the required version allowing you to install `nipy` and its dependencies.

Comment: I have accepted this solution as it solves the question, altough from @merv 's answer it seem not to be a good course of action when the pinned package is python itself.

Answer (score 6):

Changing a Python version in-place in a Conda environment has so many downsides (e.g., complicated solve; almost every package has to be redownloaded; risks breaking **base**) that whenever one requires a different Python version, the better thing to do is almost universally to create a new environment. Try instead

```bash
mamba create -n nipy_env nipy
```