# How to unpin pinned package in conda/mamba

Tags: python, conda, mamba

I have a conda environment that has a package pinned as follows:

```
Pinned packages:
  - python 3.8.*
  - bcbio-gff 0.6.7.*
  - snakemake 6.7.0.*
```

How do I remove the pin for one of the pinned packages, just using command line `conda` / `mamba`?

I've tried `conda update snakemake` but that doesn't remove the pin.

I can change the pin easily, e.g. by `conda install snakemake=7`, but then I have `snakemake` still pinned. I want to unpin `snakemake` entirely.

I had a look at potentially similar questions, but none seemed to answer my question.

Comment: Last I knew Conda doesn't provide a CLI for pinning, so why would there be one for unpinning? This would be more appropriate as a feature request rather than an SO question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is only a suboptimal answer, but it's the best I could find so far:

You need to manually remove the pinned package from a config file called `pinned` which you can find in

```
CONDA_PATH/base/envs/ENV_NAME/conda-meta/pinned
```

In my case I had to do:

```
vim /usr/local/Caskroom/mambaforge/base/envs/nextstrain/conda-meta/pinned
```

And remove the line:

```
snakemake=6.7.0
```

It would be much nicer if there was a `conda` CLI command - but it doesn't seem to exist.

Comment: Has this location changed in recent Mamba or Micromamba versions? I see that Python 3.10 is pinned in my environment, but I don't see a `conda-meta/pinned` file in the env directory. I am using Micromamba 1.5.1.

Comment: @shadowtalker I think Python is always pinned at least at minor version without being explicitly pinned in the pin file. I'm not sure there's a way to undo this pin other than to set up a fresh environment. See: https://github.com/mamba-org/mamba/issues/1245#issuecomment-976994436

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68042226/how-to-change-pinned-packages-in-mamba-package-manager

Comment: I see, Python is a special case. Thanks!